# NextJS API not called on deploy in Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a NextJS project that I uploaded to Vercel. The project works on my localhost but when I deploy it to Vercel, the APIs stop working.

Example API called from tRPC:

```
 deleteMany: protectedProcedure.input(z.string().array()).mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {

        const { userId } = ctx

        const req = await axios.delete(`${getBaseUrl()}/api/publication`, {
            params: {
                ids: input,
                userId,
            }
        })

        if (req.status === 500) {
            throw new TRPCError({ code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" })
        }

        return req

    }),
```

The tRPC does get called, but the API doesn't. I already tried with fetch instead of axios.

URL:

```
export function getBaseUrl() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") return "";
  console.log("VERCEL_URL", process.env.VERCEL_URL)
  if (process.env.VERCEL_URL) return `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`;
  return `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}`;
}
```

This is the same URL that I use to call tRPC.

tRPC does work deployed; the other APIs don't.

[image: VERCEL]

Why does that happen?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]